# Using babel package to add Persian text into English document

Tags: babel, arabic, overleaf, persian

I'm trying to add some Persian text into an English document (Springer style) using the babel package. Here is my tex file as follow:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic,farsi,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\section{introduction}
some Persian text \FR{فروشگاه}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

The issue is that using babel package changed my sections and also figure (table) numbering format (0.1 introduction in this fig).
While it is normal 1 introduction when I don't use the babel package (following image).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`arabi.ldf` (which is dead old ...) is the opinion that every class which is not article should have chapter numbers (and so you get lots of errors).

Add

```
\expandafter\def\csname ver@article.cls\endcsname{}
```

before loading babel and hope for the best.